# JQuery keyup not working IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

This code works perfectly on chrome and firefox. It only messes up on IE 10. I am using JQuery 1.11.1. In the console it appears that the keyup is not fired if you user two keys. So if I hold "alt" + "a" it will only fire the "a" keyup when I release them. In chrome and firefox it will fire both. I did not test on a earlier version of IE only 10. Also I could not get JSfiddle to work properly, I do not know how to use functions correctly in the JSfiddle.... So i am sorry :(. But here is the code. (alt Keys are being used).

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
 var altKey = false;
    function addCheckAlt(){
        jQuery(document).bind("keydown", function(e){
           if(e.keyCode === 18)
               altKey = true;
        });

        jQuery(document).bind("keyup", function(e){
           if(e.keyCode === 18)
               altKey = false;
        });
    }

   function checkIfAltKey(event){
      if(altKey){
         event.preventDefault();
         altKey = false;
         return false;
      }
      else{
         altKey = false;
         return true;
      }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-info helpBtn"
            onclick="if(checkIfAltKey(event))alert('hi');"
            value="Help"
            accesskey="6"
            title="Help (access key 6)"/>
```

when using this code just use alt + 6 and it will do a click event and click the button. If anyone can give me an idea of how to go about this at this point that would be great!! (All it does is if the alt key is being pressed then it will not do the alert)

Comment: Nice question, shame it didn't get more attention. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Just to add that in IE 11 it still does not work.

Comment: **[Quoting the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**:  *"As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."*

Comment: @Sparky Did you happen to try this in the JSFiddle? Because we are all aware of the .on functionality. Please make sure that you have done research to support your answer.

Comment: Btw... I did open a ticket with microsoft back when this was never resolved. They declared this bug as "Will not fix" With a possibility of it being fixed in a later version. Then Edge came out and I saw that it was still a bug. Haha. Just thought I would share that knowledge since I see people are still hitting this question.

Comment: @user3585563, it's not an answer... it's merely a comment containing an exact quote from the documentation, which you are free to try or ignore.  Otherwise, if you have a problem with how the docs are written or think there's a jQuery bug regarding Explorer, take it up with the jQuery team.

Comment: @Sparky, It was posted almost two years later. Yes I def took it as a possible answer. Especially since you did not say anything except quoting. But maybe that's just how I took it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by adding the next code inside the document ready function:

```
$("#TextBoxName").keyup(function () {
        debugger;
        return true;
    });
```

Hope it helps anyone that comes here like I did, with the same problem.
This works on Chrome 47.0.2526.111 and IE 11.

Adding more info:
Could not extract the code from JsFiddle but here are the bits and pieces:
HTML:

```
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/
<input id="testBoxName"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-info helpBtn"
            onclick=""
            value="Help"
            accesskey="6"
            title="Help (access key 6)"/>
<br> <br />Type Here:<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<br><br>
Results
<br /><input type="text" id="textbox2"/>
<br /><input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="log"></div>
```

Script

```
$("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
   var textinput = $('#textbox1').val().substring(0,8);
   $('#log').append('<br />Handler for .keyup() called - ' + textinput);
   $("#textbox2").val(textinput);
   $("#textbox3").val(textinput);
});

$('#testBoxName').keyup(function() {
  $("#textbox1").val("");
});
```

The check the result is that, when clicking on the button and then pressing a key, after releasing the key the first text box will be cleaned.

Comment: An explanation about why this resolves the issue would be nice.

Comment: @Sparky My idea was to associate the event to a specific element not the document it self.

Here is the link to explain how to connect an element to an event in IE
[Microsoft Keyup event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536940(v=vs.85).aspx).

I was looking for a solution that works in several browsers and one that did not use an event on the document that required taking care of the pressed key number.

Here is another great reference for events at [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Comment: @Pimenta can you create a jsfiddle of it working in IE? Just so I can mark this as resolved and it will give people a link to see it in action :). Please please!! Great work if this fixes it :).

Comment: @Justin There is the issue that 'IE is not supported' anymore by JSFiddle :(