# Input element required double click for focus in IE, how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created an input field but when I am going to enter some text, then I can type that but onkeyup event did not trigger, but when I double-clicked on the input element then onkeyup event triggered.

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="signatureName" id="signatureName" ondrop="return false;" onkeypress="return validateNameSpecialChar(this, event)" 
onkeyup="capitalizeNameString(this)" style="width: 100%;"/>
```

this is my javascript function:

```
function capitalizeNameString(obj){
    var nameValue = $(obj).val();
    nameValue = nameValue.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < nameValue.length; i++) {
        nameValue[i] = nameValue[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameValue[i].substring(1);     
    }
    $(obj).val(nameValue.join(' '));
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @JuanCaicedo, Basically I am not getting any error, but any event is not triggered on an input element, but when I double-clicked on the input element then all the events get triggered, this is only happening in IE.

Comment: What is the version of jQuery?

Comment: @EpicChen, I am using jQuery v3.5.1

Comment: By the way, what is the version of IE?

Comment: Did You Use `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()`? also I think this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661678/jquery-keyup-not-working-ie-10